# Equipment required to measure audio line-out voltage peak-to-peak?

Tags: voltage, microphone

I want to measure the output voltage coming from the line-out of my tape recorder such that the output is 5 to 6 volts peak-to-peak by adjusting the volume control.

I am new to electronics. Can this be done with a basic multimeter or will I need an oscilloscope to view the waveform?

I am trying to follow a guide on loading a program stored on cassette tape onto an old 8-bit microcomputer and this is the recommended setting.

Comment: Does the circuit mentioned in the guide show any indication that the line-out voltage is adequate ? If so, can't you use the same circuit to adjust the volume (by trial and error)?

Comment: It is not probable that a true line-out can output 6-7 volts peak to peak (standard line out is about 1 Vpp). Perhaps you need to use the headphone out.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica that's not true, full scale line outputs on most audio DAC chips are 2VRMS, or 5.6 VPP. I understand this device does not have a DAC but the level is not 1VPP.

Comment: @Justme there is a lot of interpretation, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica you are confusing nominal level with full scale peak level. You are right though, there is no standard definition how much there should be between nominal and peak in consumer devices, but for example in broadcast studios they use either 18dB or 20dB, so peaks are 8x to 10x higher than the nominal level that is used for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to find the peak value, one can potentially connect a diode and capacitor at the output of the tape recorder, and measure the DC voltage (something like a sample and hold).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF38PB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, an arduino can be set up to repeatedly sample the voltage and display the maximum.

Also, you can calibrate your multimeter with a square wave signal (because you have digital signal on your particular cassette) of known amplitude, then multiply tape recorder output with that multiplier.

Also, you can feed in 50-60 Hz pure sine wave of known amplitude into your tape recorder and measure the AC output. Most multimeters are fairly accurate at least in the 50-60 Hz range, if the sine wave is not distorted (even more true if multimeter is legally certified).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** With this method, ensure that you play a sinusoidal tone, e.g. 1kHz, but it will save you an oscilloscope...There are numerous tone generators online such as [this](https://www.mediacollege.com/audio/tone/download/).

Keep things simple. Use a multimeter with a true RMS function, which measures the effective dc equivalent of the waveform. Then multiply the RMS value by 1.414 to get the peak value. With this method you won't need an oscilloscope ;)

You can see more about the relationship between RMS and peak [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/rms-voltage-calculator/).

Comment: You can't just multiply RMS by 1.414 to get the peak value. That would only work on sine wave. Right? Why: Imagine a quiet music with a single loud pop (or bang). That'll have a very low average power but much higher peak. Another example is a 99.99% duty cycle square wave. The RMS will be (almost) the same as the peak value.

Comment: Correct! Have updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to follow a guide on loading a program stored on cassette tape onto an old 8-bit microcomputer and this is the recommended setting.

While a scope would be wonderful if you have one, the cheapest solution here will be *trial and error*.  Adjust the tape recorder to different settings and see which give you an accurate result.

It may also be worth using a computer sound card to capture these recordings and digitally archive them, using PC audio software to get a nice consistent level, and then learn what PC audio settings product a good playback for interpretation by the target device.   (If you are going to compress the files, use lossless data compression, not a perceptual audio codec, though chances are the signal is simple enough that even something designed around human hearing rather than data storage would work to a degree if the bitrate were sufficiently high)

But really the best "compression" would be to extract the original digital data from the recording.  With a little care you could probably software demodulate the signals, store them as digital data (rather than digital audio samples) and re-synthesize them on need, eliminating all analog degredation, tape speed variation, etc.  If you then know any tokenizing employed by the basic interpeter you could probably extract textual source  files.  Most likely some retro computing hobbyist has already done this... if you look around you may find a python script or something.

You are of course welcome to treat this need as justification to purchase an oscilloscope, but if you do so, get a "real" one - eg, something in the conventional form of a small bench instrument with its own display, control knobs, and at least two channels.  The less expensive alternatives all but invariably turn out to have too many limitations and quirks to make good purchases as a first oscilloscope - to the extent that they are useful, it is as compact portable devices, devices with data capture capability, etc for *experienced* users with a good understanding of the compromises made by the tool and how to work around those and interpret a display which may not be showing the real situation.  Traditional CRT-based analog scopes may occasionally be available on the *used* market and if operating and *truly* inexpensive (eg, $20 - $50), *those* might be a budget alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an oscilloscope. However not a very complex one.

10MHz should do it, and you don't even need a digital storage oscilloscope to measure amplitude. i.e., analog scope works fine for this.

I'd suggest two paths. Either go on eBay and find a used scope. Or buy the infamous Rigol DS1054 or similar if you intend to pursue electronics further.

Anyway, [old scopes](https://www.ebay.nl/itm/Tektronix-465l-B-Oscilloscope/402336454258) are also good shelf-filler since they look cool.